# How were high voltage vacuum triodes used in TVs?

Tags: schematics, vacuum-tube, tv

How were the grids of TV high voltage (over 10 kilovolt) vacuum triodes operated back in the day?

Comment: Please research wikipedia level [Cathode-Ray Tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode-ray_tube).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tubes used for the high voltage in televisions were not usually triodes (maybe in early models). Generally what you would have is a horizontal sweep tube which would be a [tetrode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrode), [pentode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentode) or [beam power tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beam_tetrode), this would drive the [flyback transformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_transformer) which would create the high voltage which would be rectified by a diode tube or solid state diode. The resulting high voltage would go to the [CRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode-ray_tube) anode.

Generally none of the tubes except the rectifier and CRT would have more than 400 V to 600 V on them. Most were used in the RF receiver and the horizontal and vertical synchronization circuits. In later sets many would be [Compactrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactron) which packed several different types of tubes into one glass envelope to save space.

If you want to learn how tube based televisions worked there are a lot of resources available on the internet, I'll start you out with [this one](https://worldradiohistory.com/BOOKSHELF-ARH/Technology/Gernsback/Gernsback-Horizontal-Sweep-Servicing-Handbook-Darr-1963.pdf) on servicing horizontal sweep circuits.

Comment: Philips Goya color TV from the late 60s contained a ballast triode PD 500 as shunt regulator for the 25 kV. This tube has a pretty nice X-Ray output.

Comment: @Jens Noted. Will look into this and update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Resistor divider.

---

I'm not sure what you're expecting from this question; the answer is trivial, if one knows where to go -- perhaps that is the real question, then?

In that case, a perusal of any contemporary data book will provide considerable illumination.  Many of these are archived online, if you know where to look (or to look for that specific thing).

[Technical books online](http://www.tubebooks.org/technical_books_online.htm)

[electron Tube Data sheets - More Tube Related Stuff](https://frank.pocnet.net/more.html)

In particular, Frank's archive (and the various mirrors) is the go-to place to look up tube datasheets.

---

As for the actual tubes, there was basically one type, the 6BK4C, and a couple practically-identical variants.

[Sylvania 6BK4C/6EL4A | Frank's electron Tube Data sheets](https://frank.pocnet.net/sheets/107/6/6BK4C.pdf)

The application is found at the end: when used as a high voltage shunt regulator, cathode goes to B+ and grid goes to a voltage divider: the top end wired to EHT, bottom to GND.  Vg1 is quite small (say -20 to 0V) so the B+ (which might be 300-400V) acts as reference, and EHT is therefore regulated to a ratio with B+.

---

The only other HV types used in receivers were rectifiers (obviously, for making the said EHT), and lower voltages -- namely sweep tubes and pulse regulators, up to 7 or 8kV peak rating.  Particularly towards the end of tube TV service (1970s or so), shunt regulators were displaced by pulse regulators, and further by transistors (first in signal-level roles, then only the power output tubes remained, and eventually the whole set was transistorized).  So, the HV triodes were only around a little while (well, that's still a few decades, to be fair).